# How TO - Add data-attribute to Current Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add an attribute `aria-current="page"` only to the currently selected element, i.e. to the active class clicked, and remove it from the non-current page?

EX.

`$('.nav__link').attr('aria-current', 'page');`

`$('.nav__link').removeAttr('aria-current');`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const selector = '.nav__link';
const elems = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( selector ) );
const navigation = document.querySelector( 'nav' );

function makeActive( evt ) {
  const target = evt.target;
  
  if ( !target || !target.matches( selector ) ) {
    return;
  }
  
  elems.forEach( elem => elem.classList.remove( 'active' ) );
    evt.target.classList.add( 'active' );
};

navigation.addEventListener( 'mousedown', makeActive );

} );
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}


.nav__item {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.nav__link {
  display: block;
  padding: .3125rem 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav__link.active  {
  border: 1px solid #ff4b4c;
  color: #ff4b4c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link active" href="#" aria-current="page">Current Page</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Source: [Highlight current page active menu item](https://codepen.io/Comandeer/pen/BZrGmM)

Comment: `$('.nav__link').removeAttr('aria-current');` then `$('.nav__link.active').attr('aria-current', 'page');` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Or are you looking for a non jQuery way?

Comment: Yes, I would like to insert the attribute `aria-current="page"` similar to how the page is highlighted as "active" when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines of code:

```
elems.forEach( elem => elem.classList.remove( 'active' ) );
evt.target.classList.add( 'active' );
```

Should be changes like this:

```
elems.forEach( elem => {
  elem.classList.remove('active');
  elem.removeAttribute('aria-current')
});
evt.target.classList.add('active');
evt.target.setAttribute('aria-current', 'page');
```

Comment: Hi @pzelenovic ! Thanks for your help. I've tried but it doesn't seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/MrGary/6zgwta81/2/

Comment: Oh, my bad, I forgot to remove `.classList` from `evt.target.classList.setAttribute('aria-current', 'page');` - here's a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mnkg18q2/ (editing my answer as well).

Comment: A hug from Italy!